# How to I add a div on the shop page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress & Woocommerce and I want to add a div on my shop page, just above the `ul` list of products. I know that this command works in the functions.php file:

```
function woa_content_before_shop() {
    echo "<h1>Hello</h1>" ;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woa_content_before_shop');
```

But when I replace the h1 tags with div tags it crashes. Can anyone tell me what I've doing wrong and/or how to correct this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean it "crashes"? post what you tried. `<div>`'ing is HTML 101 stuff.

Comment: if I replace echo "<h1>Hello</h1>" ; with echo "<div class"title">Hello</div>" ; the page fails to load @Fred-ii-

Comment: see my answer  ;-)

Comment: I made a slight edit also, you forgot the `=` sign. reload my answer just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *if I replace `echo "<h1>Hello</h1>" ;` with `echo "<div class"title">Hello</div>" ;` the page fails to load – T.Doe 15 secs ago*

that's because you did not escape the inner double quotes in there.

So do: (and you forgot an `=` sign after `class`)

```
echo "<div class=\"title\">Hello</div>" ;
```

and it will work.

Or

```
echo '<div class="title">Hello</div>' ;
```

in single quotes

Comment: Whilst I have you, I also want to add the woo commerce page title into that div, but echo '<div id="page-head"> <?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?> </div>'; doesn't work.. is there a quick fix for that too?

Comment: @T.Doe that's because you're already inside PHP and an echo, so you need to remove the `<?php echo` and `?>` from in there. You can try `echo '<div id="page-head">woocommerce_page_title();</div>';` but unsure as to how woocommerce works. I believe I answered the original question though *lol* ;-)

Comment: @T.Doe Here `echo '<div id="page-head">' . woocommerce_page_title() .'</div>';` but that should have been another question as I answered the original one, which you should have accepted.

Comment: @T.Doe your question's still considered as open btw. The question was solved so if you're not going to mark it as such, then people will think your question is still unsolved, which it was.

Answer (score 0):

Best is that you use the "template overwrite" method:

Copy the woocommerce/templates/ folder inside your theme folder, to yourtheme/woocommerce/

Inside that folder, you can modify the html structure to your heart's content and it will be used instead of woocommerce standard html templates.

Once this is done, open up these two files:

/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/shop/wrapper-start.php
/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/shop/wrapper-end.php
and modify the html to match yours.